# Does Apple accept a app with iOS6 SDK by using xcode-5?

Tags: ios, iphone, xcode

Long back I submitted an app by using xocde4.5.2 with iOS 6.1 as base SDK. Now I need give version support for my old application. 
I don't have much time to support iOS7 by using xcode-5. After goggling I came to know that, We can fix base SDK to iOS6.1 in xcode-5. I can able to run it on my iOS7 device with iOS6 appearance. 
My question is, does apple accept this kind of applications( xocde-5 with iOS6 SDK)?

Comment: Late Dezember 2013, and again at mid January 2014, Apple sent an e-mail to all developers stating that "Starting February 1, new apps and app updates submitted to the App Store must be built with Xcode 5 and iOS 7 SDK."

Answer (score 3):

No. For now all applications should be distributed with iOS 7 SDK support and with new Xcode 5.1.1. if you are uploading through Xcode.

Comment: @SureshDurishetti June 2 Apple will probably reveal the iOS 8, and release its SDK short after. I advise you to wait a couple of weeks and update your app with the iOS 8 SDK.

Comment: Even if they reveal iOS 8, you can't release apps using they release the SDK, that might be on september, so don't wait

Comment: After new SDK release all developers have a couple of monthes to adopt their application for new SDK, and at that time Apple approves uploads to AppStore with older version of SDK. But after adoption period all apps should be uploaded with new SDK support.

Answer (score 2):

Unfortunately **NO** Apple will reject your application. On December 17th 2013 Apple made an announcement stating that any application submitted to the Apple App Store Review process from the 1st February 2014 must be submitted using `xcode 5` and must be iOS 7 optimized.

You can find this announcement [HERE](https://developer.apple.com/news/?id=12172013a) but all it says is

> Starting February 1, new apps and app updates submitted to the App Store must be built with the latest version of Xcode 5 and must be optimized for iOS 7. Learn more about preparing your apps by reviewing the [iOS Human Interface Guidelines.](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/userexperience/conceptual/mobilehig/index.html)

So you will need to fix any iOS 7 issues before you submit your application.

Comment: Thanks I got the point. Can I design iOS 6 appearance in iOS 7? I move my View 20 pix down and adjust the status bar accordingly. So application look same in iOS 6 and iOS 7. Can I do this?

Comment: @SureshDurishetti As long as you optimize it for iOS 7 you can do what you want with it. However you should move with the times, the iOS 6 style days are over and you should be focusing on the new flat UI that iOS 7 offers. Focusing on iOS 7 will offer your users a better user experience and show that you are moving along with what users want. Maybe a big development phase but it needs to be done and it would be better to do it now. I delete apps that I download now that still have the iOS 6 look or try and look like they did in iOS 6, iOS 6 isn't what users want any more.